# Developing a Simmetric Key Distribution protocol to use with rfc6238

Tags: elliptic-curves, protocol-design, key-exchange, hotp

I'm trying to develop a Key Distribution Protocol to share symmetric keys in RFC 6238 (OTP).
I started with RFC 6063, but this protocol is developed over old and known insecure algorithms like PBKDF and do not take advantage of more advanced hardware like smartphones (the device I will use to produce OTPs)

The main idea is to use entropy from both server and client to generate the KEY_TOKEN.
My question. Is it a good idea to use Curve25519 to share a master key between client and server, to derive a key with HKDF to use ash K_TOKEN of RFC 6238 HMAC-SHA256 hash algorithm?
I'm not a specialist, and I can't see that the resulting key is not secure in this scenario.

PS(I Will use different algorithms to store the key in both server and client, I need to understand the risks of using this key exchange flow)
Thanks